# Use StandardSetController for edit

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardsetcontroller

I am trying to use the StandardSetController to update set of records. the code below was using StandardController to update just a single record. I want to use 
 List for the Case object to iterate through and save. How can modify this code to do so ?

```
public with sharing class ListEditor {

    ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    public string ref_suffix {get;set;}
    public Case a;
    public string ref_id {get;set;}
    public string status {get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string ref {get;set;}

    public ListEditor(ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl) {    
       controller= ctrl;
       ref = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(label.RecordType);
       ref_suffix = ref.subStringAfter(label.UNDERSCORE);
        ref_id = Utils.getRecordTypes().get(ref);
        a = ((Case)ctrl.getRecord());
        a.RecordTypeId = ref_id;
        if(a.id!=NULL){
            a= [select nameCase,statusCase from Case where id =: a.id Limit 1];
            name = a.nameCase;
            status= a.statusCase;

        } else{

        }
    }

    Public PageReference save() {
        boolean error = false; 
        a.nameCase = name;

        try {
            // some logic        
        }
        else a.name = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //some ecxeption
        }  

    Public PageReference cancel() {
        return controller.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wont completely rewrite the class for you but you can be very close to having this work with a standardSetController by doing the following

Add a controller property for a soql string

```
private string c_soql            {get;set;}
```

Set that property in your class constructor.  Just create a soql query in string form

```
soql = 'Select nameCase, statusCase From Case Where '; // you need to add your criteria here
```

Create another controller property that is your standardsetcontroller

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc {
     get {
          if(ssc == null){
               ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(soql));
          }            
          ssc.setPageSize(10);
          return ssc;
     }
     set;
}
```

Add a method to the class to return the list of cases for the VF page

```
  public List<Case> getMyCases() {
        return (List<Case>)ssc.getRecords();
    }
```